# In Rails, how can I tell, from within a model, whether the request came via a namespaced API controller or regular controller?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, api-design

I have a Rails app with a namespaced API and regular controllers that match.

Both sets of controllers of course use the same models.  E.g., API::CouponController and CouponController both use the Coupon model.

We are building features into the web side of things first and need to have some conditional logic in the model to tell whether the request is coming from the API or from the regular controller, so we can bifurcate the model logic.  How can I do this?

Or is there a way to use a different model for each pair of controllers, but point to the same table?

Comment: What do you exactly wanna do?

Answer (score -2):

Try This, I have listed a example it may be helpful

```
app/controllers/api/coupon_controller.rb

class Api::CouponController < Api::ApiController
  def index
    Coupon.test_method(params)
  end
end

app/controllers/coupon_controller.rb

class CouponController < ApplicationController
  def index
    Coupon.test_method(params)
  end
end

app/models/coupon.rb
class Coupon
  def self.test_method(params)
    return "You can check your controller and action using params"
  end
end
```

Check The controller and action in test_method

```
params[:controller]
params[:action]
```